# How to pass boolean argument to delve in VS Code?

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code, delve

I am trying to pass argument to delve through VS Code but it doesn't work.

This is how to pass argument to a go program through delve:

```
dlv debug github.com/docker/swarm -- create
```

I tried many different solution in my `launch.json`:

```
"args": [
    "--",
    "create"
]
```

```
"args": [
    "--create"
]
```

```
"args": [
    "create"
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After many attempts, I found the right one:

```
"args": [
    "--create",
    "true"
]
```